# getOrgChart.js for a supply chain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, orgchart, getorgchart

I am trying to create a supply chain in a web page

[image]

For that I use the getOrgChart plugin. The problem is that they only allowed me to create children from a parent node, and for my problem, they helped me to make my clients become my suppliers.

[image]

As you can see, I can only show my suppliers and the company in one getorgchart, and the same company with its clients in another getorgchart. My goal is to show everything in a single getorgchart.
Excuse my English, I'm Spanish.
Greetings.

the code js.

```html
 <div   id="people"></div>
 <div   id="people2"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.getJSON("listaproCS.php",function(source){
                        
                      console.log(source);

                      var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
                      var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
                         enableEdit: false,
                         enableDetailsView: false,
                         primaryFields: ["nombre"],
                         photoFields: ["imagen"],
                         orientation: getOrgChart.RO_RIGHT,
                         dataSource : source
                         });
                    });

                    $.getJSON("listaclieCS.php",function(data){
                      console.log(data);
                      var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people2");
                      var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
                         enableEdit: false,
                         enableDetailsView: false,
                         primaryFields: ["nombre"],
                         photoFields: ["imagen"],
                         orientation: getOrgChart.RO_LEFT,
                         dataSource : data
                       });
                    });
                   });
 </script>
```

The data that I get through JSON, I show them in console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhuzA.jpg)

Comment: It helps to have a very specific error or problem you are facing when looking for a solution.  It may be harder for someone to know exactaly what you need based on your description.

Comment: I understand, sorry for my question, but I see that there are not many people who use getOrgChart, there goes my question.

Comment: If you share how you are implementing showing the parent/child nodes then someone may be able to see an issue with your implementation.

Comment: Now I edit it, the data that they get to show, I get it by consulting my BD, where I have the supplier, client, company tables. I get it through JSON and I capture it in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi parent is not supported in the current version

Comment: with orgchart de jquery do you think that if you can have it?